# filtering false columns in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an amenities model that basically has a bunch of boolean columns.

I want to display the True columns in views, so I would like to filter out the false columns at the model level.

My initial thinking:

```
# in model file
 def available
    a = {}
    self.attributes.each do |key, value|
      if value
        a[key] = value
      end
    end
    a
  end
```

This is not perfect since it gives me the id, created_at, and modified_at columns.

I feel like there must be a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Deefour suggestion I ended up with this:

```
  def available
    a = {}
    hidden = ["id","created_at","updated_id","business_id"]
    self.attributes.each do |key, value|
      a[key] = value if value.class == TrueClass
      a[key] = value if [String].include? value.class and not value.empty?
      a[key] = value if not hidden.include? key and value.class == Fixnum
    end
    a
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think iterating over `self.attributes` is a fine idea. You could test `value` a bit more strictly to filter out non-boolean columns.

```
a[key] = value if [TrueClass, FalseClass].include? value.class
```